# Headless Execution with Firefox

Tags: selenium, firefox, testing, headless

Can we perform Headless execution using Firefox?  OR do we have firefox headless browser available?

Comment: Watch [**this**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPS89xCgNhk&feature=youtu.be) for Mozilla Firefox in headless mode. Headless Mozilla Firefox is implemented in the latest Firefox release v56.0 release as well.

Comment: https://medium.com/@griggheo/running-selenium-webdriver-tests-using-firefox-headless-mode-on-ubuntu-d32500bb6af2